# not least because

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of the words in bold?

"nfortunately, it is difficult to learn from the captured documents, all of which have now been released by MI5,17 precisely how Mayr succeeded in organizing such an extensive network with so few resources at his disposal, **not least because, when CICI Tehran let Schulze-Holthus loose on the records after his capture n 1944, he neatly deconstructed them**, revealing that much written by Franz Mayr in his diary and other documents was either poorly translated, wildly inaccurate, or pure imagination."

Thanks endlessly.

Comment: There is a few typos in the quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the **main** reason why it is difficult to learn from the captured documents is that Schulze-Holthus minimised their value, relevance and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

First, it tells you that it is difficult to do that task. Than says `not least` and continues with a more detailed and specific reason for this difficulty. You can interpret `not least` part as `not even a little`.

```
I couldn't eat any cake: not even a little because, it was really terrible.
```